# Encountered two children with the same key error on Material-UI with React; it keeps re-rendering Collapse every time drawer is opened

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

- **Without Key**: I first received a warning that said `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`, so I gave the `<Collapse>` a unique key of its parent, which was "Javascript".
- **With Simple Key**: It then said `Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, "javascript"`, so I then changed the key to have a `new Date().getTime()` prefix.
- **With Time Key**: The `<Collapse/>` stopped transitioning when I open and close it now.

I put in some console logs to check what goes off every time I click on the drawer button. Apparently a lot of things get called and rendered every time I click the drawer. The submenu (collapse) keeps getting re-rendered, for example, with its parent list as well.

[I created a sanxbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/moy68v2zp8) I hope the code is readable enough. I am basically passing a JSON array to dynamically put the navigation according to the list, with the top level ones staying there and the children getting a collapse for them under the parent.

I'm fairly new to both React and Material, so if there's anything I'm doing wrong do please let me know, I would greatly appreciate any tips there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are duplicating keys.
you used your key in the `ListItem`, and then passed it to the `renderSubList` function, there you created object called `Collapse` and gave him the key that is same as `ListItem`.

The most simple solution in that case is to add prefix\ postfix to the `Collapse` component, something like:

```
<Collapse
        in={this.state.subListOpen == subListParent}
        timeout="auto"
        unmountOnExit
        key={`${subListParent}collapse`}
      >
```

(checked it in you sandbox, and it's working)

Comment: Can't believe I couldn't see it. Thank you so much!